# Partial List Pagination with DisplayTag

Tags: java, pagination, displaytag

I'm having a small problem with the pagination message that displaytag is outputting for me. I'm performing pagination via the partialList method but the "displaying items X to Y" does not display correctly.

The flow is as follows:

1. user performs a search
2. query the database for the count of matching records
3. pull the correct records from the db based on the displaytag page number and number of items to be displayed at a time.
4. Set the list of items return into a dynamic struts form

However, say my query returns 15 records and we display 5 records at a time, the first page will display the message:

"15 Items found, displaying 1 to 5."

But if the user clicks onto page 2, then the same message is displayed (the row data, however, is paginated correctly).

Can anyone suggest what the problem exactly is here? PartialList is set to true on the displaytag html tag.

Thanks,
 -gearoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to upgrade to displaytag1.2

I had the exact same issue. Upgrading solved the problem.